# Can't setup PySide6, error occured when running "from PySide6.QtCore import Qt" in python

Tags: qt, pyside

I tried to install pyside6, its installation was successful (Successfully installed pyside6-6.2.4 shiboken6-6.2.4).

But I can't run the "Hello World Program" of PySide6, and when executing
`from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui`, error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libQt6Core.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

P.S.

My python version: `3.8.10`; pyside version: `6.2.4`; Linux kernel: `4.4.0-19041-Microsoft`

Comment: How did you installed PySide and how did you ran your Python file?

Comment: I followed the procedure the official document ask me to do: executing `pip install pyside6` in venv environment. I also tried again executing `pip install pyside6` out of venv environment. It turns out the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [paraview: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64588549/paraview-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-sha)

Comment: It seems that the issue can be resolved by using the command in the linked question (using the path to the libQt6Core.so.6), or by upgrading to WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved by:

`strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag  ~/env/lib/python3.8/sitepackages/PySide6/Qt/lib/libQt6Core.so.6`

This problem seemed to result from an outdated kernel (or, underdeveloped wsl kernel). Indeed, update wsl to wsl2 may solve this problem further.

Reference:

1. [Why does PySide6 on GitLab CI result in ImportError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198551/why-does-pyside6-on-gitlab-ci-result-in-importerror)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034313/ubuntu-18-4-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir/1163268#1163268